# Reading Url with React Native Deep Linking

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-native-deep-linking

I am using a deep link which sends me to my app in a specific page but I want to read the link it that page. For example: My link is "my app://somepage/code=123", I want to take this code value from url after I open the link.

Comment: You can use some javascript split concept to extract the code here. url.split('code=')[1]?.trim(); This will give you "123".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the `params` from `route`

```js
const Example = ({navigation, route})=>{
  const code = route.params.code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a method which allows me to run a function whenever I open my page.

```html
 useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      getCode();
    });
  }, []);
```

In the getCode function, I'm using getInitialUrl() function, here is the docs for more info, [https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#getini…](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#getini%E2%80%A6)
You can use this module to collect the coming url and do whatever you want.